# Why I am getting an error while trying to install gym[all]?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to install `gym[all]`, but I am getting this error message every time:

```
Collecting pygame==2.1.0 (from gym[all])
  Using cached pygame-2.1.0.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
      
      
      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...
```

And after all the output, the message is this:

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

If I try to install `box2d-py` on Google Colab, here is the error that I get:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: box2d-py
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for box2d-py (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
  Running setup.py clean for box2d-py
Failed to build box2d-py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Thanks!

I have already installed Visual Studio Build Tools. I have a similar error when trying to install on Google Colab. My Python version is `Python 3.11.3`.

Comment: I remember when `Python 3.11` came out I couldn't install Pygame. Instead I fell back and used the latest version of `Python 3.10` and it worked for me. A bit of an anti-solution, but I'd say your best bet is to use some version of `3.10`.